# How can I enter email data during signup in Django views

Tags: django

When people sign up on my website, I let them only put username and password, and I let them put their email in the username section. However, I need the Django default email section to be inputted when they put their email in the username section.

Currently, my form only has username and password section, so when they submit the form, I wanna put the data in the username section in email section. `form.email` doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.email = request.POST['username'] # I need something like this 
            user = form.save()
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL) # default : "/accounts/login/"
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Well what happens? Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Does the data go in the wrong field in your database? 'It doesn't work' helps no one. Explain what does not work, explain what happens instead, and explain what you want to happen.

Comment: Where does SignupForm come from? Did you write it? Is it a `ModelForm` or just a `Form`? Are you using the standard `User` (from `django.contrib.auth`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using model forms the `.save()` method has a `commit` parameter. If you set this parameter to False, it will create the user object without saving it to the db. You can then modify the instance however you wish.

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
user.email = form.cleaned_data["username"]
user.save()
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: @Jay Make sure to test that emails/usernames are case insensitive. You don't want to have two users with the same email or username that are capitalized differently.

Comment: Oops, you're right, should I handle that in views.py too? Can you give me a little direction for it? It would be really appreciated since I'm still pretty confused with Django

Comment: That's something you want to handle in the form. You can check if a user exists with `User.objects.filter(username__iexact=USERNAMEHERE).exists()`. It's difficult to give much more direction on that without seeing the code for your form.

Comment: You already gave me a big hint. Thank you for pointing out the issue in advance and the direction too!